# How do I code t get VWAP value of/ ON candle close(9.40AM -9.45AM) in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

After so much of going through TradingView documentation, I find I need to pass some argument like `vwap(X)` where X is nothing but HOW many bar back (from current time ) to 10.45. Any Guide or help would appreciated

Update 1
My code so far is

```
//@version=4
study("testing",overlay = true)
Time_CurrentTimeClose = time_close

Time_closeCandleAt945 = 1581394500000

DiffTime =(Time_CurrentTimeClose - Time_closeCandleAt945 )/60000
//NoOfcandleBack = 1
NoOfcandleBack=(DiffTime/5)
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none,
          text=tostring(vwap[NoOfcandleBack]))
```

Comment: I'm not quite understand your question. VWAP doesn't work with length - it works with a session (classical vwap), so it uses only data from a session it's handling. Or maybe you mean something different?

Comment: I am interested to extracted VWAP value on specific time ..let say on 5min chart, I want VWAP value on 9.45 which is candle  from 9.40 to 9.45

Comment: 9:45 candle is a candle 9:45-9:50. Anyway, if you need specific time for the vwap value, you might just step back till the bar with required time is found.

Comment: how to calculate how many behind from current time.? Updated Question for information. please check

Comment: gave an aswer below

Comment: Note, that there is a function `timestamp`, so you don't have to hardcode unix time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", max_bars_back=5000)

var vwap0945 = 0.0
v = vwap
if hour == 9 and minute == 45
    vwap0945 := v

plot(vwap0945)
// plot(vwap, color=color.red)
```

Note that it works fine only if there is a bar with a time 09:45

Comment: it says - `Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 4: Mismatched input 'var' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.`

Comment: Why it is having variation when compared with Plotted vwap value and VWAP when check manually on chart for any given time?

Comment: Oh, yes. It's "strange behavior" of series and functions called not on every bar. I changed the implementation, now it should be fine.

Comment: That was Nice implementation.Thanks. Do you make me aware some useful resources to learn good indicators. May I will come with Another Question thread on further development. ;-)

Comment: I'm not into existing indicators, I only wrine new ones. I can say that pinecoders.com and official tradingview's doc https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Introduction.html are good for learning pine-script, but I have no idea which sources to use for learning indicators